# I can not load a xml file in xamarin android

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='yes'?>
<Collection>
<Book Id='1' ISBN='1-100000ABC-200'>
<Title>Principle of Relativity</Title>
<!-- Famous physicist -->      
<Author>Albert Einstein</Author>
<Genre>Physics</Genre>
</Book>
<Book Id='2' ISBN='1-100000ABC-300'>
  <!-- Also came as a TV serial -->
  <Title>Cosmos</Title>
  <Author>Carl Sagan</Author>
  <Genre>Cosmology</Genre>
  </Book>
<!-- Add additional books here -->
</Collection>
```

i place my xml file in Resources/drawable and build action in set to Android Resources when i start the application exception occur System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.i am not sure what this exception means please help

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using Android.Content.Res;
using System.IO;
namespace App16
{
[Activity(Label = "App16", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
     string content;
        AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("Q317664.xml")))
       {
           content = sr.ReadToEnd();
       }
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("content");
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LoadXml method takes the  XML string as parameter. You are passing the string "content" to the method, which is causing the issue. As per your logic it should be

```
 doc.LoadXml(content); //without ""
```

But I also suspect if the XML is correctly loaded with this code. If this doesn't work, you may check the value of the variable content, if it has the XML string parsed into it. There is [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/#Loading_Files_Embedded_as_Resources) by Xamarin on how to load files as Embedded Resources.